# WPF MediaElement: Video opened twice

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I want to use a MediaPlayer for videos and pictures with the MediaElement. I have already done tests, the MediaElement can also display pictures.
Currently I have the problem that the MediaElement seems to open twice.
Here is the example code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestMediaElement.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMediaElement"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Margin="10">
    <MediaElement Name="mediaPlayer" MediaOpened="media_MediaOpened" LoadedBehavior="Play" UnloadedBehavior="Manual"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestMediaElement
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        int currentMediaIndex = 0;
        string[] Documents;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Documents = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Feller/Desktop/Test/");

            Uri first = new Uri(Documents[0], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            mediaPlayer.Source = first;

            mediaPlayer.MediaOpened += media_MediaOpened;       

        }

        private void media_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Video opened");
        }

    }
}
```

Another problem is that images close automatically after about 5 seconds.
Can anyone help me with these problems?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Media Element does not open twice and also the images also visible and does not close. You may be missing any code.

Comment: The Console.Write function in the MediaOpened Event is directly executed twice. I can't figure out why I'm getting this message twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaOpened event is subscribed twice. Either remove from the xaml or remove from code.

```
    //mediaPlayer.MediaOpened += media_MediaOpened;
```